# One Durable Functions App containing a generic Orchestrator which can be instantiated by other separate Functions Apps

Tags: azure, dependency-injection, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I want to have an Orchestrator which does some work using an ISomeApiClient interface. This orchestrator function should be part of one Functions App. Now, I want to have several separate Function Apps which trigger a new instance of the aforementioned orchestrator function, passing in a concrete implementation for ISomeApiClient interface. From what I have read so far, I only know one way to pass input to an Orchestrator, which is using the generic input parameter of `StartNewAsync<T>()` and using it in the Orchestrator via `GetInput<T>`, but it requires the input to be JSON-serializable and doesn't make sense with the Dependency Injection pattern. I also read about DI in Azure Functions but I don't know of a way to **construct** an Azure Function instance programmatically from another project. Is there a way to somehow invoke the Azure Functions host programmatically and pass in the dependencies from another Functions App? If not, how can I avoid creating separate Orchestrators for each new Function App with almost the same implementation, and reuse the common Orchestrator instead?

Comment: Your input is required to be serializable because it has to be able to be stored into Table Storage. Also could you clarify the other part. Do you want to start a Azure Function execution in one app from another or do you want all projects to contain a specific orchestrator implementation?

Comment: @Bjorne I want to start the Orchestrator in one Function App from another Function App, and pass the Orchestrator a concrete instance that implements an interface used by the Orchestrator. Basically, I want the Orchestrator to be generic, so it should use an interface for performing some operations, and the implementation to use for this interface should be supplied by other Function apps.